# I am getting this error "conversion to non scalar type requested"

Tags: c

Hi i am creating a sample program like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    typedef struct {
                int a;
                int b;
            }v;
v m;
int g =54;
m=(v)g;

}
```

while compiling i am getting error as `conversion to non-scalar type requested`. what is the problem here.

Comment: How can you know how to cast and not how to access members?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Conversion to non-scalar type requested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561306/error-conversion-to-non-scalar-type-requested)

Comment: The error message is right there. Do you know what a scalar type is?

Comment: no i don't know what scalar type is

Comment: That's the problem then.. http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap5/section2.1.3.html

Comment: A scalar type is a type that represents a single value, that is an `int`, a `double`, even a pointer. Examples of non-scalar types are arrays and structs. Your code is trying to cast a scalar value to a non-scalar type, and that is not allowed, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

`v` and `int` are not the same size and the compiler has no rule on how to convert from `int` to `v`.

The compiler has rules for conversion between scalar types (char, short, int, long, float, double).

If you want to assign a struct, you either need a struct of the same type, or you can assign the fields separately:

```
m.a = 54;
m.b = 32;
```

Comment: so in essence there is no really a user defined data type. assignments are done on typical datatypes only.

Comment: @mrigendra: You can assign a `struct` to another `struct`. You just can't cast from a scalar type to a non-scalar type. How do you expect the compiler to assign the memory in `g` to the `struct v`?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as it is unclear wether you want to assign 54 to `m.a` or `m.b`

```
m.a = g
```

or

```
m.b = g
```

is probably wat you want.

Comment: i thought typedef will create a datatype same as typical datatype. a typical datatype does not have any members just a size , so i am just assigning 54 as 4 bytes inside m.

Comment: typedef, in this case, is just a shortcut; enabling you to use the type `v` instead of `struct v`. you are attempting to write an `int` (probably 4 bytes) onto a `v` (probably 8 bytes, made up of 2 ints), this is where your error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The construct that you are using `(v)` is an explicit conversion or "cast". Cast are only allowed for base types (here "scalar types" in your error message), not for structure types.